# Understanding the connection between measure and function with an example of trivial sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Given a measurable space $\{\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu \}$ such that
$$\mu: \mathcal{F} \rightarrow R \ and \ \mu \ is \ \sigma-additive$$.
$$\mathcal{F} =\{\emptyset, \Omega \}$$
$$ X:\Omega \rightarrow R \ is \ a \ measurable function w.r.p.t \ \mathcal{F} \ and \ B(R)$$

I understand that X is a constant (let it be 1 for concreteness) such that
$$ X^{-1}(B) = 
\begin{cases} 
\Omega & \text{if} \ 1 \in B \\
\emptyset & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
$$

1. Does the above mean $X(\emptyset) = B' for \ B' \in \mathcal{B}(R) \ and \ 1 \not\in B'$?
2. what is the connection between $\mu$ and X ? Like would $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ make measurable function X such that $X(\emptyset)=0$

I believe I am not understanding measure and function correctly

Comment: When you write $X(\emptyset)$, are you referencing $X$ itself (meaning $\emptyset\in\Omega$ and $X(\emptyset) \in \mathbb{R}$) or are you referencing the corresponding function between power sets (so that $X(\emptyset)=\emptyset$)?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I think it's the latter

Comment: As best I can tell, your first question is purely notational, but I don't know from where the confusion stems.  Perhaps you think $X^{-1}$ refers to a function inverse of $X$?  ... For the second question, $X$ and $\mu$ can be defined independently of one another.  In particular, $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ necessarily by additivity.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, Yes, I am thinking image and pre-image like function and its reverse, so I guess such interpretation is not correct?

Comment: I would assume it's the latter as well, but then $$X(\emptyset) := \{X(\omega) : \omega \in \emptyset\} = \emptyset,$$ making your first question awkward to interpret.

Comment: I have in the past used $$X(\cdot) : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}\\ X^{-1}(\cdot) : \mathbb{R} \to \Omega\\ X[\cdot] : \mathcal{P}\Omega \to \mathcal{P}\mathbb{R}\\ X^{-1}[\cdot] : \mathcal{P}\mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{P}\Omega$$ to distinguish the two.  Just be aware that it's a common abuse of notation to use the same notation for both (since we rarely are actually inverting random variables, it's usually safe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $$X^{-1}(B)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\Omega & : 1\in B \\ \varnothing & : 1\notin B\end{array}\right.$$ means that $X(\omega)=1$ for all $\omega\in \Omega$. The things that go into $X$ are members of $\Omega$, not subsets of $\Omega$.

Based on the way your question is phrased, it looks to me like a distinction between an inverse function and a preimage. My apologies if this is not the case, and you can skip this paragraph. For sets $S,T$ and a function $f:S\to T$, $f$ does not necessarily have an inverse. But we can look at the preimage of any subset $B$ of $T$, defined by $$f^{-1}(B)=\{s\in S:f(s)\in B\}.$$  In your example, $X(\omega)=1$ for all $\omega\in \Omega$. So if $1\in B$, then for every $\omega\in \Omega$, $X(\omega)=1\in B$, and $\omega\in X^{-1}(B)$. Since this holds for any $\varpi\in \Omega$, $X^{-1}(B)=\Omega$. On the other hand, if $1\notin B$, then for any $\omega\in \Omega$, $X(\omega)=1\notin B$, so $\omega\notin X^{-1}(B)$. Therefore $X^{-1}(B)=\varnothing$ in this case.

In general, there is no connection between $X$ and $\mu$, other than that they are both connected to $\mathcal{F}$. The function $\mu$, roughly speaking, assigns a "size" to each member of $\mathcal{F}$. The function $X$ is not doing that. Moreover, for a given $\mu$, many such $X$ will exist, and for a given $X$, many such $\mu$ can exist (although it is very common to look only at one at a time).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I am getting it now, slowly though! is it wrong to interpret pre-image to be a more 'general' concept that describes the relationship between a function's domain and range?

Comment: That is exactly correct, although there is a slight sense in which these are formally different objects. For a function $f:S\to T$, the pre-image takes subsets of $T$ as inputs and returns subsets of $S$ as outputs, but (as you know) the inverse function (which exists iff and only if $f$ is a bijection) takes points of $T$ as inputs and returns points of $S$.

Comment: Let $f:S\to T$ be a function and let $2^S$, $2^T$ be the set of subsets of $S$ and set of subsets of $T$, respectively. The function $f$ generates two associated functions, $I:2^S\to 2^T$, the **image**, given by $I(A)=\{f(x):x\in A\}$. This is just the set of ouptuts of $f$ for all inputs from $A$. It is common (and a little confusing) to denote this function also by $f$ instead of by $I$, so we would write $f(A)=\{f(x):x\in A\}$. This is the **image** of $A$ (under $f$).

Comment: Similarly, there is another function $P:2^T\to 2^S$ given by $P(B)=\{x\in S:f(x)=B\}$. This is the **preimage** of $B$ (under $f$). This always exists, regardless of whether or not $f$ is invertible. It is common to denote $P$ by $f^{-1}$, which is also the notation for the inverse function (if it exists), but these are formally different objects.

Comment: If $f$ is invertible, then $I,P$ are also invertible and they are inverses of each other (so the notations $f,f^{-1}$ make sense for $I,P$ in this case). Moreover, if $f$ is invertible, we have the relationship between $f^{-1}$ and the preimage: $P(\{y\})=\{f^{-1}(y)\}$ for every $y\in T$. In other words, $P(\{f(x)\})=\{x\}$ for every $x\in S$. So we can see that $P$ acting on singleton sets is essentially the same as $f^{-1}$ acting on the points in those sets.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detail explanation !!!